# If php data is empty

Tags: php, json

I have a script that calls data from a json file. The code below works perfect IF there is data already in the json for latitude and longitude. The data is numeric. What I want to do is if the json file is empty for latitude and longitude then the following code returns a value of zero. I can't quite grasp the concept.

```
location: {
    latitude: 
    <?php 
        if (!empty($ceremony_data->latitude)) { 
            echo urldecode($ceremony_data->latitude); 
        } 
    ?>, 
    longitude: 
    <?php 
        if (!empty($ceremony_data->longitude)) { 
            echo urldecode($ceremony_data->longitude); 
        } 
    ?>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to modify your `if` conditions to return your default value, in this case 0. Something like this ought to do it:

```
if (empty($ceremony_data->latitude)) {
    echo '0';
} else {
    echo urldecode($ceremony_data->latitude);
}
```

Note that I flipped `!empty()` to just `empty()` to make it a bit easier to follow.

Comment: That did it. Thank you so much TwoStraws. I develop iPhone apps so Objective-C and Swift are in my wheelhouse. PHP is beyond me. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Internet high five for Objective-C and Swift! (I wrote https://www.hackingwithswift.com)  Glad my answer helped you; please mark it as correct so others can benefit too.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the ternary to assign a `0` or the value to a variable then just echo that variable.

```
<?php
$lat = !empty($ceremony_data->latitude) ? $ceremony_data->latitude : '0';
$lon = !empty($ceremony_data->longitude) ? $ceremony_data->longitude : '0';
?>
...
location: {
    latitude: 
    <?php echo $lat;?>, 
    longitude: 
    <?php echo $lon;?>
}
```

Comment: Protip: PHP7 includes the `??` operator which checks if the variable exists and isn't equal to NULL. `$lon = $ceremony_data->longitude ?? 0;` :)

Comment: Good point although I don't find PHP 7 widely used yet (too many questions are still using `mysql_`).

Comment: @chris87 Well, that's because PHP 7 is rather new and the repositories only still offer PHP 5.5 (if not even 5.4). So you would have to compile it yourself, if you want it. And most people don't want or know how to do that.